# How do I extract specific keywords from a string using SQL in MS Access if each string is different?

Tags: sql, regex, ms-access

I need to extract the dates from a column containing multiple keywords in different formats.

**For eg. the column looks like-**
Lifestyle Daily FY18 APR WK 4.xlsx
Outlet Daily FY18 JUNE WK 1.xlsx
Outlet Daily FY19 MAR WK 1 VS2.xlsx
Lifestyle Daily FY20 JULY WK 2A.xlsx

**I am trying to extract the keywords into a new column to look like-**
FY18 APR WK 4
FY18 JUNE WK 1
FY19 MAR WK 1
FY20 JULY WK 2

I tried using the Right and Left functions but they do not work well since the format isn't consistent

Comment: If your question is about MS Access, why did you tag this `mysql`?

Comment: Will there always be four blocks of information starting with `FY`?

Comment: Yes @LeeMac, there will always be 4 block of code starting with FY.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for MySQL 8.0 or later. See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions129.htm) for more info on REGEXP_INSTR

```
UPDATE myTable
SET newString = SUBSTRING(oldString, (REGEXP_INSTR([oldString], '%FY[0-9][0-9] [A-Z][A-Z][A-Z] WK [0-9]%')),13)
```

Comment: What about the examples with 4-char months?

Answer (score 0):

In Access SQL, you can plug a VBA function into your query.  It appears that your examples follow a pattern, so you could try something like this.  Create a module or insert these 10 lines into an existing module:

```
Function ExtractedValues(strValues As String)
Dim arValues
Dim strReturn As String
    arValues = Split(strValues, " ")
    For i = 2 To 5
        strReturn = strReturn & arValues(i) & IIf(i < 5, " ", "")
    Next
    strReturn = Replace(strReturn, ".xlsx", "")
ExtractedValues = strReturn
End Function
```

Then, in the query designer, select your table (and any other fields), and add one field with this value (change MyDateField to your raw data field mentioned above):

```
MyExtractedDates: ExtractedValues([MyDataField])
```

The result should be exactly what you're looking for, based on the examples provided.

Comment: Thank you! However, a few fields contain an alphabet or decimal number towards the end for e.g.- "WK 4a" or "WK 2.1". I am trying to get rid of the alphabets/ decimal to make it look like "WK 4" or "WK 2". This code takes the entire string after FY up till say "WK 2a" instead of just "WK 2". Is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

A helper function with one code line can do it:

```
Public Function GetDatePart(ByVal Text As String) As String
    GetDatePart = Split(Split(Text, " ", 3)(2), ".")(0)
End Function
```

**Edit**:

```
Public Function GetDatePart(ByVal Text As String) As String

    Dim Parts() As String
    Dim Part1   As String

    Part1 = Split(Split(Text, " ", 3)(2), ".")(0)
    Parts = Split(Part1, "WK ")

    GetDatePart = Parts(0) & "WK " & Left(Parts(1), 1)

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you @Gustav. This code takes everything before the full stop. However, I am trying to get rid of anything after the week number. For example- "WK 4a" or "WK 3.1" should be displayed as "WK 4" and "WK 3" respectively.

Comment: Oh, that takes a little more. See edited answer, please.